# SQLAlchemy select statement execution hangs randomly

Tags: python, mysql, sql, sqlalchemy

The following code:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

class SqlLogger(object):
  def __init__(self,
               hostname = 'xxx',
               user = 'xxx',
               password = 'xxx',
               database='xxx'
               ):
    self.engine = create_engine(
      'mysql+mysqlconnector://{}:{}@{}/{}'.format(
          user,
          password,
          hostname,
          database),
      echo=False,
      pool_recycle=300) # re-connect after 5 minutes
    self.checkout(-1)


  def __del__(self):
    self.engine.dispose()


  def checkout(self,run_number):
    connection = self.engine.connect()
    print(1)
    statement = '''
      select * from INPUT_PARAMETERS
      where RUN_NUMBER = {}
      '''.format(run_number)
    print(2)
    result = connection.execute(statement)
    print(3)
    for row in result:
      print(row)
    print(4)
    connection.close()
    print(5)


sql = SqlLogger()
```

hangs indefinitely at random times (sometimes it executes fine, sometimes it hangs). When it hangs, it will print 1 and 2, i.e., it hangs at `connection.execute(statement)`. The server I am connecting to is a google cloud sql data base. When I use localhost instead, I have no problems.

**Question:** What could be the reason for the problem? How can I avoid it?

---

**Debug infos:**

Here is the output when I use echo="debug". The number 1 and 2 are from the print commands in the script.

When it hangs:

```
2015-12-15 15:36:43,997 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'sql_mode'
2015-12-15 15:36:43,997 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {}
2015-12-15 15:36:44,070 DEBUG sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine Col (u'Variable_name', u'Value')
2015-12-15 15:36:44,071 DEBUG sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine Row (u'sql_mode', u'NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION')
2015-12-15 15:36:44,249 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT DATABASE()
2015-12-15 15:36:44,250 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {}
2015-12-15 15:36:44,322 DEBUG sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine Col (u'DATABASE()',)
2015-12-15 15:36:44,322 DEBUG sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine Row (u'SIMULATION_LOGS',)
2015-12-15 15:36:44,683 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT CAST('test plain returns' AS CHAR(60)) AS anon_1
2015-12-15 15:36:44,683 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {}
2015-12-15 15:36:44,900 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT CAST('test unicode returns' AS CHAR(60)) AS anon_1
2015-12-15 15:36:44,900 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {}
1
2
2015-12-15 15:36:45,407 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine 
      select * from INPUT_PARAMETERS
      where RUN_NUMBER = -1

2015-12-15 15:36:45,407 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {}
2015-12-15 15:36:45,486 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ROLLBACK
```

When it doesn't hang:

```
2015-12-15 15:36:37,100 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'sql_mode'
2015-12-15 15:36:37,100 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {}
2015-12-15 15:36:37,174 DEBUG sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine Col (u'Variable_name', u'Value')
2015-12-15 15:36:37,175 DEBUG sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine Row (u'sql_mode', u'NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION')
2015-12-15 15:36:37,318 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT DATABASE()
2015-12-15 15:36:37,318 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {}
2015-12-15 15:36:37,390 DEBUG sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine Col (u'DATABASE()',)
2015-12-15 15:36:37,390 DEBUG sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine Row (u'SIMULATION_LOGS',)
2015-12-15 15:36:37,779 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT CAST('test plain returns' AS CHAR(60)) AS anon_1
2015-12-15 15:36:37,779 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {}
2015-12-15 15:36:37,994 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT CAST('test unicode returns' AS CHAR(60)) AS anon_1
2015-12-15 15:36:37,994 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {}
1
2
2015-12-15 15:36:38,520 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine 
      select * from INPUT_PARAMETERS
      where RUN_NUMBER = -1

2015-12-15 15:36:38,520 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {}
2015-12-15 15:36:38,603 DEBUG sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine Col (u'RUN_NUMBER', ...)
3
4
5
```

When I insert a `connection.begin()` before the query (i.e., before the `print(1)` command), I get an actual error message instead of a freeze. Here is the debug output after the echoed statement, everything before is the same as above:

```
2015-12-15 18:47:04,044 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine 
      select * from INPUT_PARAMETERS
      where RUN_NUMBER = 1

2015-12-15 18:47:04,044 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sql_connection.py", line 44, in <module>
    sql = SqlLogger()
  File "sql_connection.py", line 19, in __init__
    self.checkout(1)
  File "sql_connection.py", line 35, in checkout
    result = connection.execute(statement)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 906, in execute
    return self._execute_text(object, multiparams, params)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1054, in _execute_text
    statement, parameters
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1146, in _execute_context
    context)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1344, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    util.reraise(*exc_info)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1139, in _execute_context
    context)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 450, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/cursor.py", line 514, in execute
    self._handle_result(self._connection.cmd_query(stmt))
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 488, in cmd_query
    result = self._handle_result(self._send_cmd(ServerCmd.QUERY, query))
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 409, in _handle_result
    columns[i] = self._protocol.parse_column(self._socket.recv())
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/protocol.py", line 234, in parse_column
    (packet, _) = utils.read_lc_string(packet)  # table
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/utils.py", line 199, in read_lc_string
    if buf[0] == 251:  # \xfb
IndexError: bytearray index out of range
```

Comment: try turn on debug mode and write here expression printed on console on what it hangs

Answer (score 0):

This is more a workaround then a solution. It seems the problem only exists when using mysql-connector. When replacing `engine = create_engine('mysql+mysqlconnector://...')` by `engine = create_engine('mysql+mysqldb://...')` I do not encounter the above error.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when using `mysql.connector.__version__ == 2.0.3`.
Upgrading to version 2.1.3 was a solution.

You can find latest version of mysq.connector on website:
[mysql connector](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/python/)